# how to parse XML with multiple child elements to array in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, arraylist

im trying to read xml file to array or list 
the xml file has multiple child elements :

```
<Items>
<Company CompanyName="company name">
    <Category CategoryName="main category name" />
    <Category CategoryName="sub category name">
        <Product MAKAT="SKU">
            <Name>name</Name>
            <Price>XXX</Price>
            <IsInStock>Yes</IsInStock>
            <URL>url</URL>
        </Product>
    </Category>
    </Category>
</Company>
```

i have tried to do this :

```
tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()
products=[]
for item in tree.findall('Company'):
    print(item.attrib)
for subitem in tree.findall('CategoryName'):
    print(subitem.attrib)
```

but i cant reach to all the elements.

i want to reach to all child elements, and insert them into one array .
what is the best way to do it in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all children by using the method iter(), like this:

```
for elem in root.iter():
    print(elem.tag)
```

If you want to store the elements in array products, you can do this with numpy: be sure to use `np.array([elem])` in order to make `np.append()` work.

Comment: thank you  . but i can add the products to the array only with numpy